# How does one use the Surveillance Fence feature in keeptrack.space?

Tags: software, tracking, space-surveillance

[keeptrack.space](https://keeptrack.space/) was mentioned in [What would be a “big picture” understanding of how the orbits of Earth satellites are monitored?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23012/12102) but I haven't visited the site since.

Running across this again today I noticed there seems to be several additional features. I lack a video game mentality and so baffled by the GUI-driven site, but I noticed the option `Set/Hide Surveillance Fence`. Clicking it generated a message to select a sensor so I chose `CSpOC Sensors`. I clicked `Set/Hide Surveillance Fence` again but nothing happens.

**Question:** What does the  Surveillance Fence feature do? How can one use and *make use* of it?

[image: keeptrack.space annotated screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

If you select any sensor, clicking the "show surveillance fence" control shows the extent of the surveillance zone that sensor uses.

For example, Cape Cod gives a planar field, with a blank area west of the sensor:

[image]

And Diego Garcia gives a conic:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... so my problem is that I can't see any satellites at all or the fence. For some reason everything seems to be turned off. I guess I'm having "operator error".  sometimes I can get orbits to show up, but no dots https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEHmf.jpg Yours look great, thanks!